# CInternetSession::OpenURL() Throws CInternetException error 1168

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When I use Afxinet to make an app to download the specified page and get the information I interested, it throws. error code 1168.

```
CInternetSession session(L"Client");
wchar_t* url = L"http://ip.chacha.cn";
CHttpFile* pfile = (CHttpFile*)session.OpenURL(url);//throws there
DWORD count = 0;
char ipline[500] = { 0 };
DWORD dwStatusCode;
pfile->QueryInfoStatusCode(dwStatusCode);
if (dwStatusCode == HTTP_STATUS_OK)
{
    CString data;
    while (pfile->ReadString(data))
    {
        count++;
        if (count == 96)
        {
            sprintf(ipline, "%s", data);
            IPv4_GET(ipline, strlen(ipline), ip);
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Error 1168 is ERROR_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.